# What happens if the statements / result sets are not closed?

Tags: java, jdbc

What are the resources consumed by a left-open result set / statement if a statement is created before each query?

Are result sets / statements closed by the garbage collection in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652336/jdbc-garbage-collection

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that you may have consequences for without closing connection. `maximum open cursors exceeded` exception you may get.

from [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

So you need to close all JDBC resources explicitly.